# How can I link an open window to the process?

Tags: process, window, handle

There is a small window that opened up on my desktop. It opened along with Windows when booting up.

[image: screencap1]

Task manager does not show it as an open window:

[image: screencap2]

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> can switch focus to the window, but it does not have a title bar.
<kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> does not see the window at all.

Visual Studio's Spy++ gives this information on it:

[image: screencap3]

And finally, Process Explorer cannot find that handle given by Spy++.

How can I find out what process this window belongs to so that I can further investigate what it is?

Comment: I might be naive here but... where's the window? Is it the white rectangle over the malwarebytes and EPUB?

Comment: At any rate, if you can get focus, can you press Alt + F4, while analyzing the Processes tab? Maybe that will tell you what process it is.

Comment: Yes, it is the white rectangle in that picture. I agree with your idea of using Alt+F4 to close it while analyzing process explorer. Although I would like to explore further ideas before closing it just to make sure.

Comment: are you worried it's some kind of virus or malware? I'd just close and not obsess over it too much, unless it happens every time.

Comment: How about going through your startup list and disabling startup items you suspect? Or just try the 'Diagnostic startup' in `msconfig` to rule out the possibility that it's something wrong internally in Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use process explorer to do this...

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx

Process explorer has its own drag icon.  If not, daphne definitely does...
http://www.drk.com.ar/daphne.php